# Name not showing up in Create Publication pgAdmin

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

When trying to create a publication for Logical Replication, the name isn't showing up on the create screen so I can't create the publication. This isn't an issue for the other server when it does show up in pgAdmin 4. The version is postgres 10.

[image]

I tried to make sure that I used superuser and that I had the correct read/write access

Comment: Whaddayamean, show up? You have to enter the name.

Comment: It's disabled for one of the servers so you can't enter a name.

Comment: I just tried it with the latest version, and I can enter a name.